# Como puedo guardar mi nombre de usuario y contraseña de mongodb atlas?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, github, next.js, mongoatlas

Estoy aprendiendo NextJS y nunca cree API's. En Next se crean de una manera facil pero exponen el usuario y la contraseña. Estoy guardando todo el código en Github y no quiero que queden expuestos. Como puedo guardarlos sin tener que usar el archivo .gitignore?

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

// POST /api/new-meetup

async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const data = req.body;

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(
      'mongodb+srv://<nombre-usuario>:<contraseña>@cluster0.gev1u.mongodb.net/meetsup?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    );
    const db = client.db();

    const meetupsCollection = db.collection('meetups');

    const result = await meetupsCollection.insertOne(data);

    console.log(result);

    client.close();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Meetup inserted!' });
  }
}

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes crear un archivo [.env](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) que deberas incluir en tu .gitignore

en ese archivo agregar tus variables de entorno:

```
MONGO_URL='mongodb+srv://<nombre-usuario>:<contraseña>@cluster0.gev1u.mongodb.net/meetsup?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

luego puedes usarlo en tu aplicacion

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

// POST /api/new-meetup

async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const data = req.body;

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    const db = client.db();

    const meetupsCollection = db.collection('meetups');

    const result = await meetupsCollection.insertOne(data);

    console.log(result);

    client.close();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Meetup inserted!' });
  }
}

export default handler;
```